# About Meta Tag and what's the use of it in HTML

Tags: html, meta-tags

I had recently started learning HTML and there is a tag called "meta tag", I didn't understand the use of that tag and its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

HTML lets you specify metadata - additional important information about a document in a variety of ways. The META elements can be used to include name/value pairs describing properties of the HTML document, such as author, expiry date, a list of keywords, document author etc.

Check this for additional info [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp). It explains meta tags clearly.Since you started to learn HTML recently,I think this web site is a great resource to learn.